# Google Sheets' operators

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Do Google Sheets have a `||` operator like most of the languages?
I'm trying to use it inside a switch function to nest some values.

```
=SWITCH(G5;"BLACKOLIVES";"BLACK";"JABOTICABA";"BLACK";"MULLBERIES";"BLACK")
```

this is how I'm doing it now, I want to do it somewhat like whats next

```
=SWITCH(G5;"BLACKOLIVES"||"JABOTICABA"||"MULLBERIES";"BLACK")
```

but this statement returns an error and I can't find a `||`-like operator in the documentation.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "like most languages". In different languages this operator can do different things, and if you mean something like the _logical OR_ operator here, it doesn't make sense to apply to strings. What do you want to happen?

Comment: i want it to do this

if G5 is "BLACKOLIVES" or "JABOTICABA" or "MULLBERIES" then cell receives "black"

without going G5:"BLACKOLIVES";"BLACK";"JABOTICABA";"BLACK"

Comment: Then use IF or IFS(OR()..) instead of SWITCH(), or if you have many such options, a translation table with a VLOOKUP()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use something like

```
=if(regexmatch(G5, "BLACKOLIVES|JABOTICABA|MULLBERIES"),"BLACK",)
```

In regular expressions the "pipe"-character means 'or'...

Answer (score 0):

an alternative syntax would be:

```
=IF(OR(G5="BLACKOLIVES", G5="JABOTICABA", G5="MULLBERIES"), "BLACK", )
```